# Can I use python to develop Google Chrome extensions?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension

I have read some introduction about how to create Google Chrome extensions. Is that possible to create the extension using Python instead of JS?

Comment: I believe you can. Check [this](http://pyjs.org/) out.

Comment: You can use Transcrypt (http://www.transcrypt.org). Disclosure of mental (as opposed to financial) interest: I made it.

Answer (score 3):

A google chrome extension is simply a webpage with a few extra permissions and so on. So, what you're looking for is basically a method to use python as a scripting language inside a browser.

The problems with this :

- Not all browsers are capable of using python as a scripting language
- By default javascript scripts are enabled in most browsers, python may not be be.
- Not enough tutorials on how to use python here. JS is way more popular.

But returning to how to do it. Popular methods:

- Brython - They use HTML5 + `text/python` scripts to directly embed python inside a browser.
- PyJS - here, they actually compile Python into Javascript. Somewhat more complicated, but finally the browser sees JS, so it is usable anywhere.